# Рекомендации по коду в Visual Studio

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

Собственно то, что мне нужно обведено на приведённом скрине. Как включить эту панель? Увидел сегодня у коллеги такую, говорит стандартное средство, дополнений никаких не ставил. Я перерыл все настройки, но у себя такой не нашёл. VS15 U2
[image: Панель подсказок]

Answer (score 2):

При детальном изучении вопроса выяснилось, что это 
CodeRush for Visual Studio от DevExpress. Установилось вместе с набором контролов для WPF проектов. Собственно по этой причине коллега и утверждал, что ничего не устанавливал т.к. ставил только библиотеку контролов, а помощник по коду установился в качестве бонуса.
По функционалу он, в принципе, идентичен решарперу

Comment: Настоятельно рекомендую еще утилиту CodeMaid Spade для студии, которая при околонулевых затратах помогает держать код в чистоте и показывает сложность методов.
Бесплатная.